# Deactivating wordpress plugins redirects to 404 and does not deactivate

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hello I am facing some problems with my website.

One of them is when I try to deactivate a plugin, I do the following:

1- click "Deactivate" under the plugin, then click "No Problem to report", when I click on that last button, I get 404 page and the plugin is not deactivated.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This question should really be posted over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You probably also want to tell us which plugins you have installed and if this is happening with all of them.  For experienced users with access to the command line, I'd recommend attempting to deactivate the plugin using [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/)

Comment: This happens with all of the plugins I have installed and its a very long list to write down here. But all of them are quality plugins with very high install base and ratings and most of them are paid.